# validates_format_of :with => locale specific regex (dynamic validation based on locale)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, locale

I have a common form for different locales. The form contains a phone field which needs to be validated against different format regex based on locales. Doing the following works however on locale change, the regex loaded on page is not updated.

```
validates_format_of :phone, :with => /#{I18n.t :'format.phone_number'}/, :message => I18n.t('message.invalid')
```

For example, if I initially loaded the page in en-US and then switch to fr_FR, the phone will be validated against en-US regex. Is it possible to have validation regex 'refreshed'? Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the switch accomplished? JavaScript? Changing the browser setting? A form submit?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, the I18n.locale is updated as I can see other label changes on the page. But to answer your question, switching via browser setting and page reload or a drop down that post to page that changes the locale.

Comment: can you show us your locale files ?